# Issues with ethereum_goerli

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, chainlink

Is `ethereum_goerli` already deprecated?

I'm trying to sell my `tLINK` using `ethereum_goerli/erc20/chainlink_token` on Ledger, but I get the following error:

```
INT…NAL_ERROR: blobs limit in txpool is full (-32000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Goerli testnet is oficially deprecated by the Ethereum Foundation, with sunset date set to April 13, 2024.

Source: Email from today (March 18) by Ethereum Foundation, received as part of their blog subscription:

> T*he Dencun network upgrade successfully activated on the Ethereum mainnet on March 13, 2024. As per the original wording of this announcement, this would imply an April 13, 2024 sunset date for the Goerli testnet.*

---

Ledger displays a warning in their [docs](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/13791830911389-How-to-create-an-Ethereum-Goerli-account?docs=true):

> *Goerli testnet is deprecated*
>
> *Starting January 2023, the Goerli testnet will be deprecated but will continue to receive support for an additional 12 months. We recommend using Sepolia for future activities.*

---

I haven't found any info from Chainlink directly. But since it's deprecated by ETH Foundation, it's safe to assume that Chainlink also considers it deprecated now. Meaning they possibly won't provide support - but the Chainlink contracts that are deployed on the network are immutable and stay onchain as long as the network is running.

---

Based on the error message, it seems that the Ledger servers don't support sending Goerli transactions anymore. But you might be still able to transfer the tokens using an alternative method. E.g. derive the private key from your mnemonic (**do not** use online tools because they might keep and misuse your keys) and interact with the Chainlink contracts directly using some of the still running RPC providers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like right everyone using Ledger Live to send ETH get this error message, not just with Goerli.

See https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/17830974229661--Internal-Error-32000-blobs-limit-error-message-when-attempting-to-send-Ethereum-ETH-or-add-accounts

Trezor users reported similar errors with the Trezor suite, too.